# Changing classes back and forth with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, class, switching

Hey guys, I have a little button functionality that is not erring, but also not working.
The addItem gets called fine, and switches the class from "add-button" to "in-cart-button", but the $("a.in-cart-button").click(... doesn't seem to be firing. When I click the "in-cart-button", instead it triggers the addItem function again... Any ideas?

```
function addItem(t_id) {
    $("#" + t_id).addClass("in-cart-button").removeClass("add-button");
}

function removeItem(t_id) {
    $("#" + t_id).addClass("add-button").removeClass("in-cart-button");
    alert("Remove item with id: " + t_id);
}

$("a.add-button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addItem(event.target.id);
});

$("a.in-cart-button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    removeItem(event.target.id);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) which binds the elements when they're found initially (by which classes they had initially), you would need [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) here, like this:

```
$("a.add-button").live('click', function(event) {
//and
$("a.in-cart-button").live('click', function(event) {
```

With [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) when the element's class changes it doesn't have an effect on the handlers, all that matters is which elements had the class when you called `$("a.add-button")` and `$("a.in-cart-button")`, it found the *elements* and bound to those...what happens to the element afterwards doesn't matter, the handlers bound to the element, not the class.  With [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) it checks the class when you click :)

Comment: Had no idea, thank you for the clarification, this works perfectly! Appreciated.

Comment: .live() is deprecated now, use .on() instead! Peace.

Answer (score 1):

That is because when the page loads, `in-cart-button` isn't on the page yet, so the handler isn't attached.

Just use one function with `toggleClass()`.

```
function toggleItem(event) {
    $("#" + t_id).toggleClass("add-button in-cart-button");
}

$("a.add-button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleItem(event.target.id);
});
```

---

Other options are to use `.toggle()` instead of `.click()` which accepts 2 (or more) functions.

Also, you could just pass reference to the function as the `.click()` handler, and still have access to the `event` object.

```
function toggleItem( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $target = $("#" + event.target.id);
    $target.toggleClass("add-button in-cart-button");
    if( $target.hasClass('in-cart-button') )
        alert("Remove item with id: " + t_id);
}

$("a.add-button").click(toggleItem);
```

Comment: I think the OP's doing additional work in these two methods, e.g. the `alert()`...but you could pass `this` to the method in either case :)

Comment: @Nick - Could be. OP could do a `.hasClass()` on the next line to get the state in the function. I have a feeling that the ID is that of the `<a>` element, which of course would simplify things more.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching a **live** event to the `<a/>` element.

see [this](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation is basically what you are looking for...

http://www.jqueryrefuge.com/2010/06/event-handling-the-delegate-way/